# While loading data from CSV to snowflake load only uniq rows

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

My CSV file is having absolute duplicate rows and while loading into snowflake database I wanted to ignore them and load only uniq rows, is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

Please check `DISTINCT` keyword in SELECT statement:

```
copy into home_sales(city, zip, sale_date, price)
   from (select DISTINCT t.$1, t.$2, t.$6, t.$7 from @mystage/sales.csv);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ALLOW_DUPLICATE = FALSE option with JSON if conversion is viable.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#syntax